# Docker run failed: no space left on device "/dev/ptmx"

Tags: docker, tty

When I try to run any Docker container with an interactive terminal, I get the following error:

```
$ docker run -it --rm my-container
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: open /dev/ptmx: no space left on device: unknown.
```

There is still plenty of free space on my current drive and the drive on which Docker is installed. The only reference of this issue I've found so far is [in this forum post](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/132635-unable-to-open-docker-console-exec-failed-unable-to-start-container-process-open-devptmx-no-space-left-on-device-unknown/), where it is suggested that the amount of pseudo terminals exceeds the threshold. I tested this on my system:

```
$ ls /dev/pts | wc -l
756
$ sysctl kernel.pty.max
kernel.pty.max = 4096
```

and I found that the amount of pseudo terminals is still far below the max value. Removing exited containers and `docker system prune` also didn't help. After `docker system prune`, the number of files in `/dev/pts` drops to 751, but the problem persists.

What's the issue and how to solve it?

- Docker version: 20.10.17, build 100c701
- System: Ubuntu 20.04

Increasing the max amount of pseudo-terminals with `sudo sysctl -w kernel.pty.max=8192` does indeed mitigate this issue, but I assume, this only pushes the problem further into the future. Isn't there a more sustainable solution to this problem?

Comment: Using lsfd or lsof, can you check what processes have those ptys open, _or_ what processes have /dev/ptmx open? Raising the pty limit can be reasonable if the ptys are necessary for the software to perform the task, but it's possible that some software is _leaking_ ptys.

Comment: But I'm a bit confused about the fact that the max number of ptys is over 4000, while the current number is 700, yet this error occurs. `lsof` reveals that most ptys are ssh and tmux connections.

Comment: 700 sounds like *a lot* of ssh and tmux sessions; are those all legitimate users or are they runaway jobs? Each container has its own /dev/pts separate from the host, so you won't see container ptys there but I believe they still add up to the system maximum.

Comment: I see. If those ptys don't show up in /dev/pts, how can I query them? Besides, when I use `lsof`, it actually shows me over 1600 applications using /dev/ptmx, 1000 of which are bash, 470 sshd and a few others. The number of users is 43.